As of 2024, why do streaming services still bother with anti-piracy protections?
From Wiki:

High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection (HDCP) is a form of digital copy protection developed by Intel Corporation to prevent copying of digital audio and video content as it travels across connections.

These sorts of protections are highly annoying because occasionally streaming content refuses to play in HD/4k resolution due to the monitor/TV not properly supporting HDCP. It's easy to solve at home but hotel rooms often don't have the right type of cable/TV, so I end up having to watch the content on my laptop screen or just pirating the show instead.
Given that 100% of (popular) content is available in 4k resolution on pirate websites... why still bother with HDCP and similar technologies?

Major studios do not license their movies and shows to a streaming platform unless their are piracy protections from one end to the other. Why they do that even if, according to you, it all is pirated anyway, I don't know.

@magarnicle its not just according to me. All 200 shows from this list of most popular shows this year can be easily found on various pirate sites. There's some rare/obscure shows and movies that can't be found there but they also don't generate much revenue for the studios.

I happen to know that a small portion of the content on pirate web sites is placed there by the studios with tags so they will be alerted when it’s downloaded with the IP address of where it was downloaded to. Then they send a letter to the ISP with a fine to pass along to the customer with that IP address. Anti piracy measures have never been able to stop piracy, they just make it harder so most people choose to avoid the hassle. It’s like locking your house or your car. You can’t prevent someone from stealing your car or robbing your house, you can only make it harder.

@ToddWilcox fighting piracy websites is definitely possible. Fighting content theft is ~impossible. You can shut down a torrent website but you can't stop someone from downloading content.

Users might have different takes on the answer, but a good, qualifying answer to this will be backed up by facts, and not be opinion-based. VTLO.
